# How to implement timeout on Redis fetch requests?

Tags: caching, redis

I have a service that uses Redis to cache some requests, but recently some of the fetches have been a little slow and I wasn't able to find any actionable items to resolve it.

```
// fetch
await this.cache.get(cacheKey)
```

I'm currently using `Promise.any` with a `setTimeout` function, but wondering if there is a built-in way to limit the amount of time this request takes? I.e. Timeout after 15 ms?

```
Promise.any([
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 15)),
    this.cache.get(cacheKey)
])
```

Comment: which client are you using? node-redis?

Comment: I'm using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis)